# Reset ARSCNView background contents to its original source

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arscnview

I'm capturing ARFrame's and applying filters, which works fine, but I want to turn off the filters and go back to the original camera feed, but I'm running into issues. This code is applying the filter:

```
 func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
  let filterImage = setFilter(session.currentFrame)
  sceneView.scene.background.contents = context.createCGImage(filterImage, from: filterImage.extent)
 }
```

Once I set `sceneView.scene.background.contents`, I cannot set it back to the original source. The original source is an object called: **SCNCaptureDeviceOutputConsumerSource**, which is not in the documentation. I tried saving that object and setting the background contents with it again, but it will just display the last frame it was holding (so there will be a still image). It does not continuously update. I don't know how to make `sceneView.scene.background.contents` extract data from the same source as it was before I replaced it.

I tried setting `sceneView.session.delegate = nil`, but that did not work, it just stops updating, and the screen looks like it freezes.

Is there a way to reset ARSCNView background contents to the original source it was getting data from?

If I reload the ARSCNView, it works, but it takes at least a second and a half to reload:

```
   sceneView.session.delegate = nil
   sceneView = nil
   sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: view.bounds)
   view.addSubview(sceneView)
   sceneView.delegate = self
   sceneView.session.run(ARFaceTrackingConfiguration())
```

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Joe, did you ever find a solution to this issue ?  The answer from Oscar is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Stackoverflow posting, If the quality of this answer isn't that high, that is the reason for it. I had the same problem as you. Here's how I fixed it.

First set the `sceneView.scene.background.contents` as a variable.
Then you can change the `sceneView.scene.background.contents` to for example `UIColor.lightGray`.

If you want to reset it back to its original Source, just do as follows.

```
sceneView.scene.background.contents = originalSource
```

Just make sure to not change the variable `originalSource`, because then you are deleting your originalSource.

Hope this helped,

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to the community, if you haven't already, read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good Q&A. Also this [another guide is a good one](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).